# How to scan for numbers, words, and quoted string and print them in sequence

Tags: java

I'm not sure how to build my stringReader method besides the fact that I want to use the getNumberLength method and getWordLength and possibly a getQuotedString method to get the lengths of the tokens and return the new counter back to the for loop so it can keep going.

You can assume that the first character of the scanned string is a letter, digit, or quote character, and that each token (number/word/quoted string) is followed by exactly one blank

ex.

input:

sweet Mannie 302 "yes"`

output:

```
word: sweet
word: Mannie
number: 302
quoted string: yes
```

So far, I have this much code -

```
import.java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment12 {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
    static String userString;
    static int numbers = 0;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your information: ");
            userString = input.nextLine();
            stringReader();
        }
    }
    public static void stringReader() {
        String recentInt;
        String recentLetters;
        String finalString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < userString.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(userString.charAt(i))) {
                getNumberLength();
            }
            if (Character.isLetter(userString.charAt(i))) {
                getWordLength();
           }
```

Comment: **what your questions are? what kind of error you get? why your code is incomplete?**

Comment: I'm not sure how to build my stringReader method besides the fact that I want to use the getNumberLength method and getWordLength and possibly a getQuotedString method to get the lengths of the tokens and return the new counter back to the for loop so it can keep going.

Comment: please add these info to your post and not in comment area